# Is it safe to upgrade to a new ubuntu base with the Software Updater?

Tags: updates, release-loki

Today I checked for any software updates available for `elementary OS Freya` through the `Software Updater` which is provided by the system. Then it notified that my system is up to date but however `elementary 16.04.1 lts` is now available and it asked me to upgrade the system. To get the complete image file [`ISO`] I went to elementary OS official [website](https://elementary.io/), but in there it provides only the `Freya` release. Why is that and if I upgrade through the `Software updater`will my machine be upgraded to the `Loki beta` version or the `lts` version. I am little confused as `lts` version is still not provided in the official website.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing this "upgrade" will not update your system to Loki. It will set up elementary OS 0.3.x with the Ubuntu 16.04 base, which will probably not work properly. When Loki is released, you can upgrade by downloading the ISO from https://elementary.io/ and doing a fresh install.

From [this answer about a similar 15.04 upgrade dialog](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3107/792):

> No, do not upgrade to the 15.04 base. Freya is built upon 14.04 LTS and only that. elementary OS' repositories do not even contain packages for 15.04 (or 15.10, for that matter). You will end up with a broken installation.

This dialog definitely is confusing, and hopefully future versions of elementary OS will get rid of it.

Comment: This dialog has _been_ removed in Loki.

Comment: That's fantastic news - thanks for the update!

Comment: From the ISO will it do a fresh install (deleting encrypted home etc) or an  upgrade is possible?

Comment: The ISO will do a fresh install - upgrading to Loki isn't possible right now. Just to be clear, clicking "upgrade" in this dialog will not upgrade you to Loki. It will upgrade the elementary base in Freya and probably break stuff.